# How can I join two tables in SQL and use function SUM on one column and show two other columns?

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

num (Table1) and id (Table2) contain the same information, so I can join them.
I can add the sum using a function in the select statement.
However, I need help adding the "location" column to my output, which comes from Table2.

How do I take the sum of all the departments for each id, and also add a location column to the output?

What I'm looking to do:

[Example tables and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGWbT.png)

What I have so far:

```
Select num, sum(amt)
From Table1
Inner join Table2 On id = num
Group by num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Select num, location, sum(amt)
From Table1
Inner join Table2 ON id = num
Group by num, location
```